# trouble retrieving string from array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working with the following function atm, but I'm banging my head against a wall.

```
-(double)fetchTimeUntilNextUpdateInSeconds{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchReq = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"DataInfo"];
    fetchReq.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"data_info_id == 1"];
    [fetchReq setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"nextupdate"]];
    NSArray *array = [self.context executeFetchRequest:fetchReq error:nil];
    NSString *string = [[array valueForKey:@"nextupdate"] stringValue];
    NSLog(@"string: %@     array count:%lu", string, (unsigned long)array.count);
    NSArray *hoursAndMins = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    int hours = [hoursAndMins[0] intValue];
    int mins = [hoursAndMins[1] intValue];

    return (mins*60)+(hours*60*60);
}
```

LOG: string: (
    "05:42"
)     array count:1

I'm getting following error: `-[__NSArrayI componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x174224060'`

fair enough, i try to invoke "stringValue" method on string (as showed in code snippet) and get the following instead:
`-[__NSArrayI stringValue:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x174224060'`

The ladder makes me think I'm already receiving a string as `stringValue` is not a method of that class.... but why won't the first work then. Better yet, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you understand the errors?? `[NSArray unrecognized selector`

Comment: Your log line seems to be saying that the thing you're calling `string` is really an array with one element.  (See the parentheses around the string.) That matches the errors you're getting when you attempt to treat an array as a string.

Comment: @user1967709 a rather strange question i would say.... yes i do... which i think is obvious based on my last sentences

Comment: Making sure, so when you used `stringValue` that only worked out okay bc the method `- valueForKey:` returns an type `id` therefore allowing you to use `stringValue` as you an tell there is no stringValue for the NSArray class. I'd suggest to you to print your elements after each line. Either save your array locally so you can see it better, or use the debugger to focus with break points, bc it looks like you haven't "gotten to the string value" you're still pointing to an array

Comment: @phillip mills I been doing all kind of ways, and I did also try to access index 0 of the array before; I did it in a wrong way. As nasty as having a nested array with only 1 object is, I think I got it fixed. Thx a lot for waking me up, I think I still need some detox from yesterday:P

Comment: @user19677709 hmm. Sry if I was unclear. What I was trying to say was that NSString does not implement stringValue. Anyway, I felt your first comment was a little feisty (considering only a harsh newbie would not recognise those errors^^), but no harm done. Have a good one

Comment: NSString wouldn't have a - stringValue and neither would NSArray, you would have to implement that yourself as a category. I do apologize for the harsh question, hard to tell where to begin on an answer without stating "well duh"

Answer (score 1):

I guess, `executeFetchRequest` returns an array containing always one item.

The mistake is the method `valueForKey` which is ambiguous. It's a `key value coding` method as well as a method of `NSManagedObject`. If you want to get the value of a key of **one** object, so first get the first object from the array and then call `valueForKey`.

```
NSArray *array = [self.context executeFetchRequest:fetchReq error:nil];
// get the value of the key `nextUpdate` of the first item of the array
NSString *string = [array[0] valueForKey:@"nextupdate"];
```

To make clear what's happening when `valueForKey` is sent to an array, see this code, it returns an array of the values for the key `id` of all members of the array.

```
NSArray *array = @[@{@"name" : @"John", @"id" : @"1"}, @{@"name" : @"Jane", @"id" : @"2"}];
NSLog(@"%@", [array valueForKey:@"id"]); // --> @[@"1", @"2"]
```

Comment: hmm, Im actually getting unrecognized selector objectForKey error with this... I think it might be because objectForKey might not be implemented for NSManagedObject. When I see your answer I thought, of course and how smooth, but since it don't work in this case, Ill have to stick with this silly code that works: NSArray *array = [self.context executeFetchRequest:fetchReq error:nil];
    NSArray *array2 = [array valueForKey:@"nextupdate_clouded"];
    NSString *string = array2[0];

Comment: then use `valueForKey` but after flattening the array. I edited the post

Answer (score 0):

Uhh, could also be the case that  ( "05:42" ) has  quotation marks that you may need to escape before you write this as a string to an array. OR you just maybe need to typecast the value of string AGAIN, but instead of doing that, why not try this first and tell us what happens.

```
NSArray *hoursAndMins = [[[array valueForKey:@"nextupdate"] stringValue] componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
```